# Where is my beta account?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, beta-badge

[[Edit] Forgot to mention, I am referring to StackOverflow. Stack* sites have really blown up these past few years!]

So I was a beta member very early on (obviously it would be early) but when I tried to login with my Google account it prompted to create a new account.

I've also created a new account the last couple times I've started using the site, but inevitable I'd forget which OpenID provider or email address I used and create yet another account.

Is there an easy way to figure out where those accounts are or what happened to them?

Comment: Which site are you referring to?

Comment: StackOverflow specifically

Comment: You may be out of luck - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: Ah yes, that's probably what happened. I was in the 'next to no activity' camp. Well who cares about badges anyway, right!?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not turning up any other accounts linked to your current email address or IP.

Without at least *some* information about them (such as which OpenIDs, other emails, or display names you may have used), there's likely not much we can do.

You can try the account recovery: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery. Feed it a few email addresses you may have used in the past, and it'll email you some information on the login credentials.

If you're able to recover any accounts that way, the next thing to do would be to give the [user merge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) help page a shot.

If none of this works, feel free to [email us directly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/other) with more details. I'd advise against posting login details, emails, etc. in public here on meta.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried every email address I could remember.  I actually still have my confirmation email sitting in my inbox! I'll give the user merge a shot.

Comment: ChrisF nailed it under the question: blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned

Comment: @AnthonyDawson Ahh, yeah, that'd do it.